# Assign values to new column based on conditions between two pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Lets say there are two data frames:
df1 contains 4 columns. The 'NAME' column contains the name of the cities (A, B, C). Each of the other columns represents a year (y0, y1, y2) containing the number of people living on that city.

```
np.random.seed(seed=34)
name = ['A','B','C']
y0 = np.random.random_integers(1,high=40, size=3)
y1 = np.random.random_integers(1,high=40, size=3)
y2 = np.random.random_integers(1,high=40, size=3)
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'NAME' : name, 'y0' : y0, 'y1' : y1, 'y2' : y2})
df

   NAME y0  y1  y2
0   A   34  36  15
1   B   22  6   30
2   C   5   12  19
```

df2 contains 3 columns. The column 'NAME' contains the name of the cities. The 'y' column contains the value of the year (y0, y1, y2) and the 'i' column contains the number of people who have internet access.

```
y = ['y0', 'y1', 'y2',  'y0', 'y1', 'y2',  'y0', 'y1', 'y2']
name2 = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C']
i = [15, 6, 12, 18, 4, 20, 3, 8, 2]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'NAME':name2, 'y':y, 'i':i})
df2

   NAME y   i
0   A   y0  15
1   A   y1  6
2   A   y2  23
3   B   y0  18
4   B   y1  17
5   B   y2  20
6   C   y0  3
7   C   y1  24
8   C   y2  2
```

I need to create a column on df2 that contains the values ​​of df1 with the condition that the value of df2['NAME'] is equal to df1['NAME'] and df2['y'] is equal to the df1 column , in order to get the following result:

```
   NAME y   i   v
0   A   y0  15  34
1   A   y1  6   36
2   A   y2  12  15
3   B   y0  18  22
4   B   y1  4   6
5   B   y2  20  30
6   C   y0  3   5
7   C   y1  8   12
8   C   y2  2   19
```

The number of times that the cities names appear on df is not constant.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: what column is `df2['y']` suppose to equal?

Comment: it is supposed to be equal to one of the "year" (y0, y1, y2) columns in df1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, since the values match:

```
df2['v'] = df.melt(col_level=0, id_vars='NAME').sort_values(by='NAME').reset_index(drop=True)['value']
```

output:

```
  NAME   y   i   v
0    A  y0  15  34
1    A  y1   6  36
2    A  y2  12  15
3    B  y0  18  22
4    B  y1   4   6
5    B  y2  20  30
6    C  y0   3   5
7    C  y1   8  12
8    C  y2   2  19
```

or with combinefirst

```
df3 = df.melt(col_level=0, id_vars='NAME').sort_values(by='NAME').reset_index(drop=True)  
df3 = df3.rename(columns={'variable':'y'})                                                                                         
df3 = df2.combine_first(df3)
df3['value'] = df3['value'].astype(int)


  NAME   i  value   y
0    A  15     34  y0
1    A   6     36  y1
2    A  12     15  y2
3    B  18     22  y0
4    B   4      6  y1
5    B  20     30  y2
6    C   3      5  y0
7    C   8     12  y1
8    C   2     19  y2
```

Answer (score 0):

a merge would be better imo,

```
df = pd.melt(df,id_vars='NAME',var_name='y',value_name='v')

df_new = pd.merge(df,df2,on=['NAME','y'].sort_values('NAME')
print(df_new)
  NAME   y   i   v
0    A  y0  15  34
3    A  y1   6  36
6    A  y2  12  15
1    B  y0  18  22
4    B  y1   4   6
7    B  y2  20  30
2    C  y0   3   5
5    C  y1   8  12
8    C  y2   2  19
```